# Cannot use keyboard or mouse after disabling CSM and enabling secure boot

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios, mouse

I cannot use my keyboard or mouse ever since I enabled secure boot and disabled csm on my desktop. I can’t even use these when I get into the BIOS (by pressing Del at startup). After I go into BIOS, my keyboard and mouse don’t work.

I’m just stuck with the black screen prompting to press F11 for boot menu or Del for BIOS setup.

And I have tried resetting the PC.

How do I fix this?

Comment: With CSM disabled, the legacy USB support may not work, so you may need UEFI specific USB HID support.

Comment: How do I get that when I can’t use my mouse or keyboard?

Comment: Try plugging your keyboard into a different USB port. USB HID support may be limited to either USB2.x or USB3.x ports.

Comment: Didn’t work either.

Comment: your motherboard probably has a user manual

Comment: Can anyone here help? I have tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me a few months ago, and today as well. What happened was, I was trying to get my PC ready for Windows 11 installation, where Safe Boot is required, so I tried to enable it. Well, in order for Safe Boot to be enabled, I needed to disable the CSM and then, what happened was even worse than your case. Nor keyboard, mouse or MONITOR were turning on! I had no control over my PC and I was blind as well.

What I had done was resetting the BIOS to default values (that is to clear CMOS). If there is a CLR_CMOS (Clearing CMOS Jumper) jumper on the motherboard, you may place a jumper cap to temporarily short the two pins or use a metal object like a screwdriver to touch the two pins for a few seconds. (You may refer to the manual about where CLR_CMOS located.)
You literally touch the two pins together with a screwdriver for a few seconds. After that, BIOS reset to its default values and everything worked again.

Hope that helps.